# Нужна помощь с пониманием функций высшего порядка

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Наткнулся на статью на хабре (https://habrahabr.ru/post/154105/) и в ней на пример,видимо простейший, который не могу понять)

```
function makeAdder(base){
    return function(num){
        return base + num;
    }
}

var add2 = makeAdder(2);
add2(3); //5
add2(7); //9
```

Первую часть, в принципе, частично понимаю (var add2 = makeAdder(2);). Мы задаем переменной base значение 2 (если я все правильно понимаю, конечно) и присваиваем переменной add2 функцию. А вот дальше (add2(3);) не понимаю никак. Каким образом мы таким способом меняем значение num? если кто-нибудь сможет разжевать, буду дико благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вызывается `makeAdder(2);`, то в `add2` складывается не просто функция `function(num)`, а, фактически хардокрно жёстко прописывается значение `base`, переданное ранее. В итоге получается вот так:

```
add2 = function(num) { 
    return 2 + num; 
}
```

поэтому при вызове `add2(3);` получается, что передаем значение `num` равное 3 и его складываем с захардорженной двойкой. Аналогично с `add2(7);`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Правильно понимаю, что при вот этой записи var add2 = makeAdder(2);  я, по сути, присваиваю переменной add2 функцию function(num){ return base + num; } + присваиваю переменной base значение, которое в данном случае равно 2, то есть, грубо говоря, присваиваю колбэк функции makeAdder()?

Comment: да... только это не колбэк, а возвращаемое значение всё же.

Comment: Понял. Большое спасибо)

Comment: Если хотите, можете попробовать какую можно написать функцию, чтобы можно было вызвать к примеру так:  
var add2 = makeAdder(2);
add2(3)(4);

Comment: Как-то так?) https://jsfiddle.net/44f16sqa/